# Braintree payment method nonce is not receiving

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, braintree

I'm trying to use Braintree with Angularjs 1.5.x and nodejs. I'm using 'dropin' UI. UI form to select payment method is rendered but i'm not receiving paymentMethodNonce which is required for payment settlement at backend.

```
 $scope.getBrainTreeCtoken=function(){
        //Get BrainTree Client Token
        $http.get('/payment/clientToken').then(function(res){
            braintree.setup(res.data.clientToken, 'dropin', {
                container: 'payment-form',
                onPaymentMethodReceived:function(nonce,type,details){
                    console.log('nonce '+nonce);
                }
            });
        },function(err){
            console.log('error '+err);
        });

    }
```

This is frontend code which renders dropin ui at specific container but i don't see any xhr calls when i enter credit card info such as card number and cvv which will be passed to braintree server and payment method nonce is returned. Document states paymentMethodNonce will be added automatically as hidden field but i didn't get anything. When i submit form the form submits as i'm calling a function in angular(functionally it differs from default form submission). Let me know how did you integrated BT with Angularjs 1.x.

Comment: Does your console log a nonce value?  It looks like in their examples, the onPaymentMethodReceived function only receives one argument.  Can you pass in one argument into that function, and parse out the nonce?  For example;

onPaymentMethodReceived:function(data){
                    console.log('nonce '+data.nonce);
                }

Comment: Actually, there is no xhr call to BT server for nonce because i'm not submitting html form in traditional way. I received answer from BT support team. Will update once i make my flow working. Thanks.